# sum all visits by customer in the next week

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I need to count of future visits by specific customer in the next 7 days.  I solved this with `purrr:map2` but I'm experiencing very slow performance.  I think I must be missing something basic about how to use `purrr`.  How do I speed this up?  Thanks

This toy example takes 2.3 secs with 100 rows, but 3.3 minutes with 1000 rows on my machine.  My actual data has 400K rows!

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
rows <- 1000
df= data.frame(cust_num = sample(c("123","124","128"),rows,replace=T), 
               date = sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/31'), by="day"), rows, replace=T))

df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate( visits.next.7.days = map2_lgl(df$cust_num,df$date,~.x==cust_num&.y>date&.y<(date+7)) %>% sum() )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that uses `purrr::reduce` to sum the list of vectors returned by `data.table::shift` (a vectorized version of `lead`/`lag`). `pmap_int` with `sum` would do the same as `reduce` with `+` if you like, but it a little slower. You could similarly do `map(1:7, ~lead(n, .x, default = 0L))` instead of `data.table::shift`, but it's more code and slower.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
rows <- 1000
df = data.frame(cust_num = sample(c("123","124","128"), rows, replace = TRUE), 
                date = sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), 
                                  as.Date('2017/01/31'), 
                                  by = "day"), 
                              rows, replace = TRUE))

df2 <- df %>% 
    count(cust_num, date) %>%
    group_by(cust_num) %>% 
    # add dates with no occurrences; none in sample data, but quite possible in real
    complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 'day'), fill = list(n = 0L)) %>% 
    mutate(visits_next_7 = reduce(data.table::shift(n, 1:7, type = 'lead', fill = 0L), `+`)) %>% 
    right_join(df)

df2
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 4
#> # Groups:   cust_num [?]
#>    cust_num       date     n visits_next_7
#>      <fctr>     <date> <int>         <int>
#>  1      123 2017-01-09    10            78
#>  2      128 2017-01-19    12            70
#>  3      124 2017-01-05    15            73
#>  4      128 2017-01-27    14            37
#>  5      128 2017-01-27    14            37
#>  6      123 2017-01-15    19            74
#>  7      124 2017-01-24    12            59
#>  8      128 2017-01-10    10            78
#>  9      124 2017-01-03    19            77
#> 10      124 2017-01-14     8            84
#> # ... with 990 more rows
```

This may not be the most efficient algorithm, as depending on the spacing of your data, `complete` could potentially expand your data dramatically.

Further, with data this size, you may find data.table is more practical unless you want to put your data in a database and access it with dplyr.

Comment: would this be "cleaner" with a pure data.table solution?

Comment: If it's equivalent, it wouldn't be particularly cleaner or worse, though it would likely be quicker. To be cleaner, it'd really need a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `zoo` package. The idea is to group the data by `cust_num` and `date` and count the row number first, and then use the `lead` function to shift the count number by 1 and use `rollapply` to calculate the sum of the next six days (not include the beginning date). Finally, use `left_join` to merge the results back to the original data frame. This should be much faster than your original approach. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df2 <- df %>%
  count(cust_num, date) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(n2 = lead(n)) %>%
  mutate(visits.next.7.days = rollapply(n2, width = 6, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE, 
                                        align = "left", partial = TRUE)) %>%
  select(cust_num, date, visits.next.7.days)


df3 <- df %>% left_join(df2, by = c("cust_num", "date"))

head(df3)
#   cust_num       date visits.next.7.days
# 1      123 2017-01-09                 70
# 2      128 2017-01-19                 54
# 3      124 2017-01-05                 58
# 4      128 2017-01-27                 37
# 5      128 2017-01-27                 37
# 6      123 2017-01-15                 68
```

Comment: thanks, that works.  I am trying to understand how to work with `purrr`.  does anyone have a `purrr` solution?